# Rendering dynamic user interface depending on the settings saved in database

Tags: java, javascript, html, css, angularjs

I have a situation.

I have one setting page through which I can modify the settings of the User Interface page.

This settings page contains information about colors and images to be shown in user interface page.

When I make changes in this settings page and save it then configuration gets saved in database.

Now I want to use these saved settings in DB for rendering client side UI.

HTML pages will remain common and depending on the settings saved in DB I need to update its interface.

Comment: can you provide a plunker or give us detail what kind of changes you looking? do you want to change classes, imagesURLs...?

Comment: Yes class properties should be changed and also imageURLs depending on the configuration saved in database

Answer (score 0):

Everything you bind with a controller can be changed so easily...

for example you can use `ng-class` for using dynamic class like this

```
<button ng-class="buttonClass1">Button One</button>
```

which can be changed dynamically when you edit **buttonClass1**...

and same for `ng-src` for image src...

here is a little [DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/sibxzzeIwRhP5GWprrsH?p=preview) for you to observe this...

**UPDATE**

here is update [DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/sibxzzeIwRhP5GWprrsH?p=preview) for `ng-style` and another good [EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/mrajcok/eTTZj/) both contains `ng-class` and `ng-style`

Comment: We don't want use any css while rendering UI. All class properties should be rendered dynamically. What if I want apply multiple properties for single HTML element

Comment: I dont have classes but styles. Can it be applied dynamically through ng-style?

Comment: Thanks for your update. WE used following approach1. Put all the required css inlined to the html in a style tag, create all the default css classes inlined.
2. Use ng-class to load the default inlined css on the component.
3. Load all the user interface settings from database in angularjs controller.
4. Replaced the properties value of the default inlined css class with the project specific css values using ng-style.

Comment: @VinayakKedge if this is solution for you pls upvote and accept it as a answer...